# El uso del “cuánto/a/s” + adjetivo

Tags: gramática

> ¡Cuántos imbéciles hay en el gobierno! Hay que reemplazarlos.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el plural y el singular?

> ¡Cuánto imbécil hay en el gobierno! Hay que reemplazarlos.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que nada, observa que *imbécil* en estos ejemplos está usado como un sustantivo, no como un adjetivo. Es decir: *un imbécil* = *una persona imbécil*. Por eso, además, es que puede aparecer junto con el cuantificador *cuánto(s)*.

La diferencia es de tono y registro. La forma "correcta" es la primera, la que está en plural (*cuántos imbéciles*), porque obviamente se habla de muchas personas (y en la oración que sigue se las refiere con el pronombre en plural, *-los*). Pero en forma coloquial se puede cambiar el plural por el singular.

En este caso *imbécil*, que es un sustantivo contable (*un imbécil, dos imbéciles, tres imbéciles*), se transforma o funciona como un sustantivo no contable (como *agua*) o un sustantivo colectivo (como *gente*). El significado es el mismo, pero decir *cuánto imbécil* es más expresivo y suena más despectivo, como si todos esos imbéciles formaran una masa amorfa.

Este concepto se usa con *cuánto* pero también se puede usar con otros cuantificadores, como *tanto*, *mucho*, *bastante*, *demasiado* y también su opuesto, *poco*. Por ejemplo:

- A una persona que llenó su casa de libros:

  > *¿Tanto libro tenías que comprar?*
- Observando que hay muchos turistas en una plaza:

  > *Hay mucho turista por aquí, ¿verdad?*

Hay que tener cuidado con usar esta expresión con grupos de personas porque puede sonar ofensivo.

Comment: +1 Muy completa la respuesta, Pablo. Me gustó lo de "masa amorfa" (mucho imbécil: muchos seres del tipo "imbécil", que responden a esa clasificación). El singular en estos casos tiene en efecto una carga subjetiva que está ausente en el plural (más objetivo). También llama la atención que casi siempre se usa con cuantificadores que indican abundancia, no escasez (pero ocasionalmente se podría usar "poco/a": En este barrio rico hay poco auto usado.)

Comment: @Gustavson Es verdad que *poco* (y *poquito*) también se usan. No se me había ocurrido. Tampoco se me ocurrieron buenos ejemplos para los otros, más que nada porque siempre dudo de si son muy coloquiales o simplemente cosas que yo diría pero que están "mal" (y justamente de esta clase de cosas es muy difícil encontrar registros escritos).